# Bond Orientational Correlation Function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, simulations, correlation-functions, liquid-crystal

Firs this question has some similarity with [Bond order correlation function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/461153/bond-order-correlation-function?rq=1) and [Bond Orientational Correlation Function - how exactly to calculate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/511981/bond-orientational-correlation-function-how-exactly-to-calculate) but its a little bit different , so having those context i am going to evaluate the bond orientational correlation function which has the form $$g_6(x=|x_i - x_j|) =\langle\psi_6(x_i) \psi_6^*(x_j)\rangle .$$ where $$\psi_6(x_i) = \frac{1}{N_i}\sum_{i=1}^{N_i}{\exp(i6\theta_i^j)}$$
is the 6-fold local orientational order and $N_i$ is the number of nearest neighbors of particle $i$ and can be evaluated using voronoi weighted method.
and $\theta_i^j$ is the angle between the line connecting the particle $i$ with $j$.

however I get confused by the meaning of this $\langle *\rangle$ what kind of average is this exactly? does anybody had ever evaluated it? since eventually i would like to calculate it in a computer , perhaps a python code or some hints might also be usefull.

Answer (score 1):

This here,(⟨∗⟩) is an ensemble average, this runs over all the particles in the system.
Hints for writing the code,
Frist: Use Voronoi tesselation to find the nearest neighbors or you may use KDtree(found in scipy module in python)

Second: You will have to loop over all the particles, by calculating the ψ6(xi) for each of the particle.

I will post the code if you fail to write it!

Comment: I have been struggling with it for so long, and yet it seems I failed to write down a proper code to calculate it. Therefore, I really would appreciate it if you could post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a reference axis with respect to which $\theta$ is defined.  For each particle, calculate $\Psi_6$ as in the second formula by using the angle $\theta_i$ that the bond between the particle and each of its 6 (or 5, or 7) neighbors makes with the reference axis.  We now have a complex number $\Psi(x_i)$ for each particle $i$.

Choose an arbitrary particle $i$ and calculate $g(x=r)$ centered on that particle as in equation 1: you will bin the locations of other particles $j$ by their distance from $r = |x_j-x_i|$ from $x_i$.  In each annnulus at distance $r_n$ there will be some number of particles $N$.  Find the average of the value $\Psi(x_i) \Psi^*(x_j)$ for each annulus by taking this value for all particles $j$.  The real part of the value indicates to what extent the direction of bond orientation at the distance $r_n$ is aligned with that of the central reference particle at $x_i$.  Doing it for each annulus, you have a list of values $g(r_n)$ for each $r_n$, or a function giving correlation of bond angle as a function of distance from a particle.

For greater accuracy, go through using each particle as the central reference particle $x_i$ in turn and average the resulting $g(r)$.

Comment: ok so let me back up a little, what is the best already-written function to find the nearest neighbor particles using the Voronoi methods?

Comment: @Jason scipy.spatial has voronoi methods, check their docs for how to process your points and obtain lists of neightbors

Comment: So I am in the middle of writing a code for what you described; however, I did not fully understand what you mean in your last paragraph. Could you please explain it a bit more clear?

Comment: You have chosen a random particle as center and retrieved a description of how correlated things are as a function of distance from that particle?  This has a lot of random noise for how things happen to be arranged around the one particle in particular.  Try choosing a different random particle x_i and the function will look different.  Try retrieving it for many different choices of x_i. To get rid of noise and find what all these functions have in common due to properties of the material, you can look at the average of many such functions.