# Compute properly bond order correlation radial function $g_6(r)$

Tags: experimental-physics, correlation-functions

I'm trying to compute the bond order radial correlation function for experimental data set about colloids in 2D. I already have the position of the colloids in a variable `pos[numatom,dim]`, with dimension (Number of atoms, 2). I have tried to compute the correlation with the algorithm explained below. I have compared this with the results from a program that I now that works properly and not able to find the same result... but I don't see where is the error in my code. I have not found any explanation that make me happy to understand how to compute it, so... questions:

(a) How should I compute the $g_6(r)$ correlation for a given snapshot of my system? In case that the steps that I'm doing are wrong, can anybody tell me step by step what I have to compute?

(b) If it is possible, how I now if this correlation is normalized or not? In case it is not normalized, how can I normalized this correlation?

---

---

1. Compute Voronoi Tessellation of the system to find the $N_{ij}$ neighbors of the particle $i$, enumareted with $j$

```
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi
vor=Voronoi(pos[:,0:2],furthest_site=False, incremental=False, qhull_options=None)
```

2. Loop over all particles and compute hexagonal order parameter for particle $i$ at position $\vec{r}_i$ using the $N_{ij}$ neighbors at the position $\vec{r}_j$:
   $$\psi_6 (\vec{r}_i)=\frac{1}{N_{ij}} \sum_{j=1}^{N_{ij}} \exp[i \, 6 \, \theta_{ij} ]$$
   where $\theta_{ij}$ is the angle between the relative position of the particle $\vec{r}_{ij}=\vec{r}_j-\vec{r}_j$ and the x-axis (chosed for convention). Using the dot product to compute the angle
   $$ \theta_{ij} = acos\left( \frac{x_{ij}}{|\vec{r}_{ij}|} \right) $$

```
import math
### Number of particles
nparticle=len(pos[:,0]) 
### Vector to save psi6 per particle
psipp=np.zeros((nparticle))
### Loop over all particles
for i in range(nparticle):
    cont=0
    suma=0
    ### List of neighbors for particle i
    list_neigh=vor.ridge_points[vor.ridge_points[:,0]==i,1]
    ### Loop over all neighbors of particle i
    for j in list_neigh:
       ### Relative distance between i and j
       dx=pos[i,0]-pos[j,0]
       dy=pos[i,1]-pos[j,1]
       dd=dx*dx+dy*dy
       mrij=np.sqrt(dd)
       ### Angle between x and rij
       theta=math.acos(dx/mrij)
       suma+=np.exp(1j*6*theta)
       cont+=1
    if cont>0:
       psipp[i]=suma/cont
```

[image]

3. Onces I have the value of $\psi_6 (\vec{r}_k)$ for all $k$ I compute the local bond order correlation function
   $$ g_6(|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_i|) = \psi_6 (\vec{r}) \cdot [\psi_6 (\vec{r}_i)]^* $$
   to do so I pick a particle $i$ and select it as the center one. Then I bin the space in circular shells with distance between $r=|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_i|$ and $r + dr$ away from the particle $i$ (as in radial distribution function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_distribution_function) and compute the sum of $\psi_6 (\vec{r}) \cdot [\psi_6 (\vec{r}_i)]^*$ over all de particles between these distances
   $$ g_6(|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_i|) = \frac{1}{count}  \sum_{j=1}^{count} \psi_6 (\vec{r}_j) \cdot [\psi_6 (\vec{r}_i)]^* \quad \quad \quad $$ with $$r< |\vec{r}_j-\vec{r}_i| < r+dr $$
   Loop over all the particles $i$ to compute the ensemble average
   $$ g_6(r) =\langle g_6(|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_i|) \rangle = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N g_6(|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_i|) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \psi_6 (\vec{r}) \cdot [\psi_6 (\vec{r}_i)]^* $$

```
Nbin=200       ## Number of bins to compute the function
rmax=1000      ## The function is computed from 0 to rmax [in pxels]
dr=rmax/Nbin   ## Bin size [in pixels]

g6=np.zeros((Nbin))
for i in range(nparticle):
    for j in range(nparticle):
         dx=pos[i,0]-pos[j,0]
         dy=pos[i,1]-pos[j,1]
         d2[i,j]
         mrij=np.sqrt(d2[i,j])
         n=int(mrij/dr)
         if(n<Nbin):
             g6[n]+=psipp[i]*np.conj(psipp[jj])/(psipp[i]*np.conj(psipp[i]))
g6[:]=g6[:]/nparticle
```

I hope this help to solve the other questions related to this correlation function [https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/461153/bond-order-correlation-function, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/511981/bond-orientational-correlation-function-how-exactly-to-calculate, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/581260/bond-orientational-correlation-function]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be about code checking.

Comment: @Gert Sorry if this looks like code checking, I can simplify the question. I just need to know the explicit steps to compute the bond correlation function. I have tried to compute it as is explained in one of the commends of this post (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/581260/bond-orientational-correlation-function) but it doesn't look trivial to me...